# How to import escaped data from MySQL to JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

In my MySQL database I have the folowing row:

`\"test\"` | `\'test\'` | `\'test\'` `\"test\"`

If I import that to JSON I will get that:

```
[
    "\"test\"",
    "\'test\'",
    "\'test\' \"test\""
]
```

which will generate erron in JSONLint:

```
Parse error on line 2:
...    "\"test\"",    "\'test\'",    "\'t
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Why the below code doesn't generate error in JSONLint?

```
[
    "\"test\"",
    "\\'test\\'",
    "\\'test\\' \"test\""
]
```

And how to import data (by PHP) from MySQL to get the above result?

Comment: Are the \ characters actually in the database?

Comment: yes there are the by mysql_real_escape_string function

Comment: I mean did the original data include backslashes, before being escaped? mysql_real_escape_string adds backslashes for the SQL statement, but when mysql processes the statement it removes the backslashes. The point I'm making is that you have to distinguish between what's actually in the data and how the data is represented as literals in PHP and SQL. If there really were backslashes in the data, the JSON should look like `[ "\\\"test\\\"", "\\\'test\\\'", "\\\'test\\\' \\\"test\\\"" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` (a built in function in PHP) on the resultset from MySQL.

**Small example**

```
$a = Array(
    '\"test\"',
    '\'test\'',
    '\'test\' \"test\"'
);
echo json_encode($a);
```

*Outputs*

```
[
    "\"test\"",
    "'test'",
    "'test' \"test\""
]
```

The function cleans up any data you send to it before JSONLint receives the data.

Read up more on [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).